# Loadrunner 12.53 install stalls on windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, server, loadrunner

Install stalls during "Status: Applying Configuration" the status bar is at about 10%. and has been for over an hour. Task Manger says 0% cpu

This windows 2012R2 Patched up to date, DEP is limited, and I'm running the install as admin. 
LoadGenerator 11.52 was installed previously, that was uninstalled and the server restarted.

This server is not connected to the internet

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like patience was the answer. 
I went back to the server a couple of hours later and found the install had moved onto prompting for a CA cert

I suspect "Status: Applying Configuration" task was either :-

- looking for and trying to download software updates, and as this machine didn't have internet connection it eventually timed out, and/or
- Writing registry keys.